# What does \x do in print

Tags: perl

I would like to start by saying that I am not familiar with Perl. That being said, I came across this piece of code and I could not figure out what the `\x` was for in the code below. In addition, I was unsure why nothing was displayed when I ran the following:

```
perl -e 'print "\x7c\x8e\x04\x08"'
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not about print: it's about string representation, in which codes represent characters from your character set. For more information you should read [Quote and Quote-like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) and [Effects of Character Semantics](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#Effects-of-Character-Semantics)

In your case the character code is in hex. You should look in your character set table, and you may need to convert to decimal first.

Answer (score 4):

You said "I was unsure why nothing was displayed when I ran the following:"

```
perl -e 'print "\x7c\x8e\x04\x08"'
```

That command outputs 4 characters to STDOUT.  Each of the characters is specified in hexadecimal.  The "\x7c" part will output the [vertical bar character](http://www.mclean.net.nz/ucf/?c=U+007C) `|`.  The other three characters are control characters, so probably wouldn't produce any visible output.  If you redirect output to a file, you will end up with a 4 byte file.

It's possible that you're not seeing the vertical bar character because it's being overwritten by your command prompt.  Unlike the shell `echo` or Python's `print`, Perl's `print` function does not automatically append a newline to all output.  If you want new lines, you can insert them in the string using `\n`.

Answer (score 3):

\x signifies the start of a hexadecimal character notation.